# Optional group doesn't match anything

Tags: python, regex

I use the following regex, but it doesn't work

```
([^@]+)(?:_@(\d+))?
```

> Variable_Name_1
>   
> Actual:
>       \1 = Variable_Name_1
>       \2 = null
>   
>   Expected:

```
\1 = Variable_Name_1
\2 = null
```

> Variable_Name_1_@4
>   
> Actual:

```
\1 = Variable_Name_1_
\2 = null
```

Expected:

```
\1 = Variable_Name_1
\2 = 4
```

Do you have some ideas to solve my problem ?

Comment: What tool or programming language/library do you feed the regex to?

Comment: Also, can yo describe in words, what you are trying to match? Are you simply trying to make the part starting with `_@` optional? Or the strig `_@` itself optional?

Comment: I use Python, I have a string in input, and i want to match the variable name and her index.i'm trying to make _@ optional, and i need to save the digit after the @ (if he exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the only requirement, regular expressions are overkill. How about this instead:

```
>>> "variable_name_1".partition("_@")
('variable_name_1', '', '')
>>> "variable_name_2_@5".partition("_@")
('variable_name_2', '_@', '5')
```

Comment: You have right, i don't need regex to solve my problem. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches the first kind of string properly, but does not match the second kind properly.

Removing the last `?` in your regex matches the second kind of string properly, but no longer matches the first one properly.

I believe the reason is that making the second part of the regex optional, makes the first part too greedy. I do not know if there is a *modifier* that will make your regex work, but a combination of the two regexes will work:

```
>>> re.search('(?:([^@]+)(?:_@(\d+))|([^@]+))', 'Variable_Name_1_@4').groups()
('Variable_Name_1', '4', None)
>>> re.search('(?:([^@]+)(?:_@(\d+))|([^@]+))', 'Variable_Name_1').groups()
(None, None, 'Variable_Name_1')
```

What you need now is just post-process the tuple to have two elements where second is maybe `None`.

Alternatively, you could manually try matching against the first regex, and then against the second regex in a utility function.

Comment: Exactly ! i need to use another group. I think the best way is to use the `partition` function in Python